# ADF Sink File Naming Oddity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My Dataflow is writing data to a delimited text sink; the file naming pattern looks like this:

[image: Sink settings]

When the files are ultimately written out to ADLS, the file names look like this:

[image: Actual filenames]

I can't find any documentation on where the "-00001" is coming from. Does anyone know, and more importantly, how to turn it off?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reprod the same error what you are getting by keeping the same Sink settings as per you.

My `Sink setting` looks like in below snippet.

[image]

My **Parameter** value is shown below.

[image: Blockquote]

You also need to have a look into `Sink’s Optimize` tab where you will be able to see the `Partition option`. **For `File name option` as `Pattern` under Setting tab, `Partition option` will be by default `Use current partitioning`**.

[image]

Now, this is how my Sink data looks like in Storage after running the pipeline.

[image]

To resolve this issue, under Setting tab keep `File name option` as `Output to single file` and under `Optimize` tab, keep `Partition option` as `Single Partition`. Refer below images for the same.

[image]

[image]

Now, when you run your data flow, the single file will be created with the same name as of your parameter.

[image]